# geom_line does not generate lines using fun.y = mean as an argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data:

```
head(BCM)
        fips      scc pollutant emissions  type year
114288 24510 10100601  PM25-PRI     6.532 POINT 1999
114296 24510 10200601  PM25-PRI    78.880 POINT 1999
114300 24510 10200602  PM25-PRI     0.920 POINT 1999
114308 24510 30100699  PM25-PRI    10.376 POINT 1999
114325 24510 30183001  PM25-PRI    10.859 POINT 1999
114329 24510 30201599  PM25-PRI    83.025 POINT 1999

table(BCM$type)
NON-ROAD NONPOINT  ON-ROAD    POINT 
 416      142     1119      419 

table(BCM$year)
1999 2002 2005 2008 
320  535  542  699
```

I want to look at how the pollutant varies across time for each type. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = emissions), data = BCM) +
geom_point(stat = "summary", fun.y = mean) +
facet_wrap(~type, scale = "free")
```

[image: with geim_point]

What I really want to do is to connect the dots to form lines. So I thought this would work:

```
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = emissions), data = BCM) +
geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = mean) +
facet_wrap(~type, scale = "free")
```

But what I got is many lines of warnings and a plot with no points or lines on it:

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group     aesthetic?
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image: with geom_line]

I'm relatively new to **R**. So please somebody tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about flipping it around for

```
#sample data
gg<-expand.grid(type=letters[1:4], year=2000:2004)
df<-data.frame(
    gg,
    emissions=runif(nrow(gg)*10)
)

ggplot(aes(x=year, y=emissions), data=df) +
   stat_summary(geom="line", fun.y="mean") +
   facet_wrap(~type, scale="free")
```

[image: stat summary line]

Comment: I couldn't generate line plot with your solution... But I used geom_histogram instead to visualize the data better than points.